# How to get a Hover-Reveal Tools Antd functionality on React-table?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-table

I am migrating some tables from Ant Design to React-table version 6.*
Some Antd tables are using the [Hover-Reveal Tools](https://ant.design/docs/spec/lightweight#Hover-Reveal-Tools) and it's working fine.

Is anybody aware of a similar functionality in React-table 6 and how can I implement it?
I couldn't find any similar feature on react-table 6 documentation/examples.
If there is no such functionality, as I think it is, what is the best way to implement it on react-table?

Thanks